# How can I change a URL using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to show the URL

```
http://www.example.com/about-us.php?p=ceo-greeting
```

as

```
http://www.example.com/about-us/ceo-greeting
```

How can I do so using `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^about-us/(.*) /about-us.php?p=$1
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete documentation on mod_rewrite.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html