# change url with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have an url in the following format:

```
http://example.com/realestate/index.php?page=services.html
```

How can change it to the following format with a `.htaccess` file?

```
http://example.com/services.html
```

So that `index.php?page=` is omitted and only `services.html` part is shown in the browser's 
url.

I dont know anything about writing .htaccess files.

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I change a URL using .htaccess?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4564338/1124792).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)\.html http://example.com/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Now the url xyz.com/services.html would be rewritten to xyz.com/index.php?page=services.html